# Awk - Split each byte to their own file while specifying created filename to stdout

Tags: awk, split

I have huge files (multiple gigabytes, etc) and while i tried many different tools (split, etc) but for my own needs i need to do this in awk.

Basically, i want to emulate what `split -b 1 file` does (which from the man page and command provided, it split file by one byte each) in awk.

I also want the generated files to have their filename (incremented) printed to stdout, while the script is running, mostly so i can use those as variable and such in other script.

EDIT: here what i did so far

```c
awk '{for(i=1;i<=length;i++) print substr($0, i, 1)}' filename
```

***Filename details***

The filename need to be incremented so as to not overwrite other files. (either numeric or alphanumeric).

To compare, `split` tool from coreutils generate filename using letters, like so: `xa xb...xaa`

I want to have either that, or if possible numeric only:`1 2..444`
or/and alphanumeric filenames:`a1 a2`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107449/discussion-on-question-by-nordine-lotfi-awk-split-each-byte-to-their-own-file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C gawk -v RS='.{1}' '
  {
    file = "filename" ++n
    print file
    printf "%s", RT > file
    close(file)
  }' < input
```

But given that it creates one file per byte, on most filesystems, you will likely quickly run out of disk space (as 1-byte files still occupy several kibibytes of disk space on most file systems) or inodes, or the performances will become dreadful after a few hundred thousands bytes of input (as the cost of adding an entry to a directory increases with the size of the directory with several file system implementations)

- `LC_ALL=C` is for `.` to match on a byte instead of character
- `RS='.{1}'` sets the record separator to `1` single character (which are single bytes with `LC_ALL=C`). `RS=.` would not work as it would mean the record separator is the dot character. You need `RS` to be more than one character for `gawk` to consider it as a regular expression. `(.)` and `.|.` would also work, but in my tests, I find `.{1}` is the most efficient of the 3.
- `RT` contains the text that was matched by `RS`.

`RS` as a regexp, the ability to deal with binary data and `RT` are all non-standard extensions. `RT` is GNU-specific AFAIK.

Comment: yeah, well aware of the effect of what i'm doing :)
however, how do you specify a file to this? tried it by appending the file at the end of the command, and tried using a pipe but got no output.

Comment: @NordineLotfi, see edit.

Comment: Thanks, that work.

Comment: what if i want to make it work with ascii character too? tried it with a test file with `hello world` but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: also just fyi, but the filename isn't printed to stdout, work for binary file though.

Comment: @NordineLotfi, I missed the *print filename part* from the requirements. Should be fixed now. See edit. It should work regardless of how the text is encoded, it prints bytes as they are read, it doesn't care whether it's text or not let alone how that text is encoded.

Comment: yep, seems to work great now, thanks again!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21401299/8017719 Which declares that: *This means that it would require more than 4 TB to create an ext4 file system with "-Tnews" that could possibly hold 1 billion inodes.* A 1Gbyte file becomes a 4Tbyte filesystem. That is a 4000 times bigger.

Comment: Interesting post, didn't found that one before! @Isaac (though i already knew part of what it said, still interesting)

Comment: `RS='.{1}'` can be written `RS='(.)'` as well.

Comment: @αғsнιη, good point, I'll see which is most efficient (I fear `(.)` might trigger some extra form of saving of the matched data)

Comment: @αғsнιη, yes, it's significantly more expensive than `.{1}` and even than `.|.` in my tests. Actually, I don't notice a significant difference between `.{1}` and `.|.`.

Answer (score 1):

As all that `split` does (when generating 1 byte files) is to number the files in order but generate only up to 256 distinct files. There are no more possible contents of files, just 256.

And, as the conversion of a multi gigabyte file into the same amount of files with 1 byte each will increase the size of the data to process in a big factor (more than 4000 in a ext4 filesystem) and will make accessing each file slow.

There is, however, an alternative as you also say that you are going to do additional processing on your data:

> I also want the generated files to have their filename (incremented) printed to stdout, while the script is running, mostly so I can use those as variable and such in other script.

Thus: a much faster solution that considerably reduce the consumption of resources (disk space, processing power, time and energy) will be to:

- Generate 256 files, each with one byte from `0x00` to `0xff`. That covers any possible input.
- Generate in stdout `a number` + `a file name`. The number is the position in input file from the start. The file name is one of the 256 files created above to give the value of the byte inside the input.

You could generate the 256 files beforehand (bash):

```
for((i=0;i<=255;i++)); do 
    file=prefix$(printf '%03d' "$i"); 
    printf '%b' "$(printf '\\x%x' "$i")" >$file;
done
```

Or just generate the ones needed while processing the multi gigabyte file:

```
LC_ALL=C gawk '
  BEGIN{                                # 
      RS=".{1}"                         # set the record separator
      for(i=0;i<256;i++){
          ord[ sprintf("%c",i) ] = i    # help array ord
      }
  }
  {
    position = ++n                      # keep count of bytes read
    file = "prefix" ord[RT]             # find the file name to use
    if ( ! seen[file] ) {               # Have we seen this file ?
        printf "%s", RT > file          # If not, create it.
        close(file)                     # close the file
        seen[file]=1                    # record that we have seen it.
    }
    print position, file                # print information for next script
  }
' ./input                               # file to process.
```

In short: A faster solution.