# Bash - How to write different output to incremental filename

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write multiple output from a script to their own file, with incremented filename.

```
INPUT="$1"

# while loop
while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
        # display one character at a time
    echo "$char" > filename
done < "$INPUT"
```

this is what i did so far, although it doesn't have the incremental count. Since the script print one char at a time, i need it to be put in it's own file, with an incremental or alphanumeric filename, so there no overwriting of the files.

Comment: `"$num"`  is defined/created some where?

Comment: ah my bad, was doing experiment to implement what i asked, but forgot to delete this it seems (did delete other stuff that didn't work), will clean this up.

Comment: Is this essentially different from your other question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583716/awk-split-each-byte-to-their-own-file-while-specifying-created-filename-to-std)?

Comment: yes, slightly different. although they are similar in goals, one need to have the output filename (which is generated/incremented) to stdout, while the other one doesn't. One is in bash and the other in awk.

Comment: just wanted to have different version of the script for sake of planning and testing things out.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're reading a file and not a string yes?

Comment: yes, i'm reading a file, but if the script/tool can accept stdin, then string would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a file name per string plus the increment.

```bsh
input="$1"
counter=1
while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
  ((counter++ <= ${#input} ))
  echo "$char" > "filename$char$counter"
done < "$input"
```

To print the output to stdout and to the file, change

```
echo "$char" > "filename$char$counter"
```

To

```
echo  "filename$char$counter" | tee "filename$char$counter"
```

If you need to parse a string need more test for the input and then

```
 < <(printf '%s' "$input")
```

instead of

```
< "$input"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :D

Comment: any ways to add a way to display the incremented filename to stdout too? @Jetchisel

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: just FYI, but while it does work, i noticed that it add an additional byte (0a), you can try a simple word as input, and use hexdump -C on it to see what i mean.